# parent to child record changes using trigger

Tags: case, field-update, master-detail

I have trigger on parent object which is used to update field Status of child object, I want to update child object's status field to Tested only if previous values is "ready for testing". And once all child status field changes to "Tested" i want my parent object field changed to 'Awaiting deployment.'

I just need suggestion for this part. "**I want to update child object's status field to Tested only if previous values is "ready for testing". And once all child status field changes to "Tested" i want my parent object field changed to 'Awaiting deployment.'**"

How to approach this scenario, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use trigger.oldmap (to check the previous value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely recommend reading through the best practices found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices).

Here's an overview of how you can approach this:

1. Create your trigger (probably before insert, before update?)
2. Query for the child records that meet your criteria and put them in a list.
3. Make changes to child statuses.
4. Make changes to parent fields.
5. Update records.

Heres a watered down example of the child portion that might help:

```
   trigger updateChildStatuses on Parent__c (before insert, before update) {

        // Query child records
        Child__c[] childRecords = [SEELCT Parent__c, Status__c FROM Child__c WHERE Status__c = 'ready for testing' AND Parent__c in :Trigger.new ];

        // Update the child records
        for(Child__c c :childRecords){
            c.Status__c = 'Tested';
        }

        update childRecords;

        // Handle your normal parent field updates here
    }
```